# vim script E749 empty buffer, E488 Trailing characters when using &filetype?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set key mapping like this (set key mapping exclude two filetypes):

```
let LIN_VIM_NVIM_TREE='NvimTree'
let LIN_VIM_FERN='fern'

nnoremap <expr> <Leader>bn (&filetype ==# LIN_VIM_NVIM_TREE || &filetype ==# LIN_VIM_FERN ? "\<C-w>\<C-w>" : "").":\<C-u>BufferNext\<CR>"
```

But it reports error:
[image]

But this one is working (only one `&filetype`):

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>bn (&filetype ==# LIN_VIM_NVIM_TREE ? "\<C-w>\<C-w>" : "").":\<C-u>BufferNext\<CR>"
```

Why two `&filetype` comparison is not working?
It looks like the 2nd `&filetype` is an empty string?
How should I exclude two filetypes when set key mapping?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `&filetype`: `:help map-bar`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, looks like it's `|` issue in my mapping.

Comment: I changed `||` to `<Bar><Bar>` then the mapping works!

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @romainl's comment. I replaced my key mappings from `||` to `<Bar><Bar>` and it's working now!